# Lookbehind with the ^ character in a Ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex

Why, in Ruby, do the first two regexes fail to match while the third matches?

```
str = 'ID: 4'
regex1 = /^(?<=ID: )\d+/
regex2 = /\A(?<=ID: )\d+/
regex3 = /(?<=ID: )\d+/

str.match(regex1)  # => nil
str.match(regex2) #=> nil
str.match(regex3) #=> #<MatchData "4">
```

The only difference is the `^` or `\A` characters, which match the beginning of a line and beginning of the string, respectively.  It seems both should be matched by `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The look-behind pattern `(?<=ID: )` matches a *position* in the string that is preceded by `«ID: »`.

The anchors `^` and `\A` match a *position* at the beginning of the line or string.

So the pattern `\A(?<=ID: )` asks that both match together, i.e. that the beginning of the string is preceded by `«ID: »`. Not gonna happen!

Comment: While correct, this answer is a proper subpart of my answer. It adds nothing new, and is less.

Comment: @sawa: Is that what your answer says? Although I didn't downvote you I find your words very confusing, and it seems at least two others agree with me.

Comment: How is it confusing? I edited a bit. Can you be kind enough to tell what is confusing?

Comment: *+1* from me... :) great answer.

Comment: Your sentences are far too long, and you have marked `regex1 = /^(?<=ID: )\d+/` etc. as code fragments when they are not. You haven't explained your conclusions *"There is no string that has such point"* etc.

Answer (score 4):

Both of these would work fine if you put the anchor inside of the lookbehind:

```
regex1 = /(?<=^ID: )\d+/
regex2 = /(?<=\AID: )\d+/
```

If the anchors are outside of the lookbehind then you are saying "from the start of the string, are the previous characters `ID:`".  This will always fail because there won't be any characters before the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Look-ahead and look-behind are non-capturing/zero-length, so the first two expressions don't match.

The first expression, for instance, amounts to another way of writing: `/^\d+/` (it's conditioned on `\d+` not being preceded by a space, but that's not possible since there cannot be anything before `^` anyway).

Answer (score 1):

In the third expression, the lookbehind can occur anywhere and specifically occurs in the zero-width space before the `4`.  You can see that [only the `4` is matched](http://rubular.com/r/QiTpfhyavX).

With `^` or `\A`, the zero-width space at the beginning of the string must match the lookbehind, which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

- In `regex1`, which is `/^(?<=ID: )\d+/`, there has to be a beginning of a line that is preceded by `ID:`. The string in question does not have such point.
- In `regex2`, which is `/\A(?<=ID: )\d+/`, there has to be a beginning of a string that is preceded by `ID:`. There is no string that has such point.
- In `regex3`, which is `/(?<=ID: )\d+/`, there has to be a point of string that is preceded by `ID:` and is followed by `\d+`. There is such point in the string.

Comment: Downvoters, I hope you understand English. The word "or" can be interpreted in several ways with respect to logical scope. Don't interpret it in the wrong way and downvote it.

Comment: I do hope you understand the point of *punctuation*. You're not writing a legal document.

Comment: @Borodin I don't get what you mean.

Comment: Your sentences are far too long, and you have marked `regex1 = /^(?<=ID: )\d+/` etc. as code fragments when they are not. You haven't explained your conclusions *"There is no string that has such point"* etc.

Comment: @sawa: I think your (correct) answer is hard to understand because "a beginning of a line that is preceeded by `ID:`" describes the reverse order the elements are put in the regexp. There, the `ID:` comes **after** the `^`. Borodin's answer does a better job in explaining that. +1, btw.

Comment: @undur_gongor Thanks for the comment, but I tried to reflect the order in the regex. `^` or `\A` represents "a beginning of ...", and after that comes the `(?<=...)`, which represents "preceded by ...".

Comment: @sawa: Yes. But you applied additional logic. In fact, the 1st regexp is a beginning of a line followed by digits that are preceded by `ID: `. You reduced this which is correct but still makes it a bit harder to follow.

Comment: Yes, for the first two regexes, I only showed necessary conditions, which are not satisfied. By not mentioning the additional condition (to match `\d+`), I intended to make the logic simpler. I don't get why it is considered harder.

Comment: I guess you'll have to put up with it ;-) Sometimes, people just don't understand you.

Answer (score 0):

Look-behind doesn't change position of the match.

`/(?<=ID: )\d+/` is actually matched at the digit:

```
ID: 4
    ^
```